# PHP Get Data Attribute From HTML5

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

I've got some problem!

> I want to show both news-evt and news-ntc content in my web page.
>   The JS can POST "news-evt, news-ntc", but the PHP cannot process with this result, how can I do? I am new of php and ajax... Thanks!

My Table:

```
**id**   **category**
  0        news-evt
  1        news-ntc
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="blog-filters">
    <li data-vid="news-evt, news-ntc"><a>All</a></li>
    <li data-vid="news-evt"><a>Event</a></li>
    <li data-vid="news-ntc"><a>Notice</a></li>
</ul>
```

My JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#blog-filters li', function(){  
        var last_id = $(this).data("vid"); 
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:"load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",
            data:{last_id:last_id},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data) {
                if(data !== '') {
                    $('.post-item').remove();
                    $('.btn-load-more').remove();
                    $('.blog-content-rows').append(data);  
                }  else  {  
                    $('.btn-load-more a').html("No More...");  
            }},
        });
    });
});
```

My PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['last_id'])){

    require_once('datalogin.php');
    $last_id = ($_POST['last_id']);
    $showLimit = 3;
    $output = '';  
    $id = '';
    sleep(1);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE (category LIKE '%".$last_id."%') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$showLimit) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)  {
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
            $id = $results['id'];
            $output .= 'Something Code...';
        }
    }
}
```

> Solved: Simply change`$last_id = $_POST['last_id']` to `$last_id = explode(',',$_POST['last_id'])` and then add `foreach ($last_id as $item) {$raw_results = mysql_query............}`
>
> New Problem: But there is a Order problem...the foreach loop output 'evt' result first...

Comment: It makes no sense to use LIKE in this case in your SQL query. You have _two_ values, and the column only contains _one_ value. You either want to use IN(), or make that two separate conditions to check for. And you need to go read up on SQL injection.

Comment: You can see the error thrown by checking your error log. Also, which version of PHP are you using (you can see that either through your hosting provider, if you have command-line access (`php -v`) or if you create a file that simply reads `<?php phpinfo()` and access that page through the browser)

Comment: PHP 5.4 by Goddady

Comment: **Please** stop using the deprecated mysql_* API. Use mysqli_* or PDO. Then you can avoid the security concerns associated with this library and use parameterised queries to properly protect yourself against SQL injection attacks. Concatenating strings the way you are doing leaves you wide open to hacking. Also mysql_ is removed entirely in PHP7 as well, so whenever you upgrade to this version your code will cease to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `echo` of PHP.

```
<div class="blog-content-rows"> 
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['last_id'])){
        require_once('datalogin.php');
        $last_id = ($_POST['last_id']);
        $showLimit = 3;
        $output = '';  
        $id = '';
        sleep(1);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE (category LIKE '%".$last_id."%') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$showLimit) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)  {
            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
                $id = $results['id'];
                $output .= 'Something Code...';

                //new code here:
                echo "<div>ID: ". $id ."<br/> Output: ". $output ."</div>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

The result would be like:

```
<div class="blog-content-rows">
    <div>ID: 1<br/> Output: Some_text</div>
    <div>ID: 2<br/> Output: Some_other_text</div>
    <div>ID: 3<br/> Output: Another_text</div>
</div>
```

Feel free to ask for anything else.

Comment: Yes, It can show all the content in the page, but I added 3 category buttons in my page 1. All  2.Event  3.Notice........When I start the page, it shows All......when I click Event, it shows Event.....But when I click All button, it not work.....

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to write the code, but I will try.